# Excel: How to Subtract two different cells that contains set of values each

Tags: excel

I have Excel data which consists of 2 columns:

```
FirstColumn        SecondColumn
1.0,3.0,4.5,2.5    0.5,0.75,2.25,1.25
2.0,0.5,2.3        1.75,1.5,2.0
1.5,2.0,3.0,4.0    0.75,5.0,2.0,3.75
```

Is there any way to subtract those two columns and acquire the subtraction result of each row? 
The expected result is something like this:

`row1: 0.5,2.25,2.25,1.25`

Would greatly appreciate if someone could help. Programming in python is okay too. 
Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to write a VBA user defined function for this.

Comment: Use Split() on each value to convert to two arrays, then loop over the array elements and subtract each pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My explanation is in the code comments.

```
Option Explicit

Function mutliDifference(str1 As String, str2 As String, _
                         Optional delim As String = ",")

    Dim tmp1 As Variant, tmp2 As Variant, i As Long

    'cteate arrays from the strings passed into the function
    tmp1 = Split(str1, delim)
    tmp2 = Split(str2, delim)

    'ensure that the arrays of are of equal size
    ReDim Preserve tmp2(UBound(tmp1))

    'Debug.Print LBound(tmp1) & ":" & UBound(tmp1)
    'Debug.Print LBound(tmp2) & ":" & UBound(tmp2)

    'loop through arrays and perform subtraction
    For i = LBound(tmp1) To UBound(tmp1)
        tmp1(i) = Format(Abs(tmp2(i) - tmp1(i)), "0.00")
    Next i

    'create string from subtraction results
    mutliDifference = Join(tmp1, delim)

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for asking another question, is there any way to add abs() function in the module? Thank you very much.

Comment: tbh I purposely reversed the subtraction so you could figure out the functionality. :) If you understand what I've provided above, implementing Abs() shouldn't be an issue.